# Docker Nginx image starts, but fails with error "port already in use"

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

I have docker container with the [alphine-nginx](https://github.com/ilagnev/docker-alpine-nginx-lua) image. I push 5 Nginx configuration files to this container, but it does not work and fails with a "port already in use" inside the container. Each configuration file contains an different port, but it fails on start.

`error.log` has:

```
019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2447 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2450 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2448 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to 0.0.0.0:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: bind() to [::]:2449 failed (98: Address in use)
2019/10/13 14:57:17 [emerg] 21#21: still could not bind()
```

`netstat -ltnp` info:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:33623        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2447            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2448            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2449            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2450            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 :::2447                 :::*                    LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 :::2448                 :::*                    LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 :::2449                 :::*                    LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
tcp        0      0 :::2450                 :::*                    LISTEN      9/nginx: master pro
```

As I see, something starts Nginx, but how to check what is it?

Docker ps:
[image: Docker ps]

Comment: show your dockerfile, seem like Nginx try to start again while there is already another process or Nginx that occupied the port.

Comment: @Adiii https://pastebin.com/L8aSVv84 I've added it here, please check it

Comment: main file is missing `/opt/startup.sh`

Comment: @Adiii yes, sorry, forgot about it https://pastebin.com/9vqU4aLx

Comment: @Adiii I should note that for other colleagues it started without any troubles. I guess it does not matter for docker due to containerization, but on windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 (client) it works, on macOS it does not work.

Comment: that's strange, but the error is seem from inside container, as it up from last one hour. just try to change this line in startup script `nginx -g daemon off`

Comment: in such cases, only one can debug, so I will suggest two thing, one as above second thing, change nginx port in config file `server {
    listen 81;
}` and then up the container do run command in container and check which process occupied the port in container.

Comment: @Adiii did all you said, still got `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:*service port* failed (98: Address in use)` for each service (where service port is current port for current service)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200779/discussion-between-adiii-and-alexxosipov).

Answer (score 1):

You have a process of id (PID) of the process which have taken the port.
You can use `ps -p 9 -o comm=` to get a command line for this process.

I think it is docker. In this case try `docker ps` to get the list of running docker containers.

And you can just kill this process by `kill -9 9`.

**Updated:** I have tried to run container by `docker run nginx:1.17.4-alpine` and don't have any problem. If you build custom image or use additional settings or configurations which a different from default - you need to describe them.

Comment: Add `docker ps` result to the question